# When to used Stream in Flutter and what are there advantages over looping with Future?

Tags: flutter, dart, async-await, stream

I have a function that takes a folder path and generates an image for each file found.
This generation takes a while and is really CPU-intensive.

I'm new to Flutter and I'm used to using Futur but not Stream.

I would like to know what would be the advantage of using a Stream over just using SetState in my case.

From what I can read Stream sounds perfect for my used case but I think I miss the point when I look at the code I produced.

Here is the code:

```
 Future<void> _foo(Directory dir) async {
    List<File> files = _findFiles(dir);
    for (File file in files) {
      Widget image = await _computeImage(file);
      _imageStreamController.add(image);
    }
  }

void _bar() {
    _imageStreamController.stream.listen((event) {
      setState(() {
        _imagesList.add(event);
      });
    });
  }
```

or

```
 Future<void> _foo(Directory dir) async {
    List<File> files = _findFiles(dir);
    for (File file in files) {
      Widget image = await _computeImage(file);
      setState(() {
        _imagesList.add(event);
      });
    }
  }
```